# update listview items without clear()

Tags: java, android, listview, android-volley

Hello everybody I am newbie in android so my problem is I have app where I usin volley and have json response and stored it in Arraylist so when i pull to refresh it gives me doubled data if update three times it gives three copies of data again how to solve this?i solve it like this but itS took many time to update if there exist many data---

```
 List.clear();

//volley request
 ...
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`
```

so how to refresh it without clear should I store it in Set but i should have ordering of datas also I  can delete some data in server side and thats datas also needs to be deleted in listview HELP HELP HELP

Answer (score 1):

Here is the link it may help you "https://stackoverflow.com/a/5092426/1632286".This link discuss all the possible solution regarding this.

Comment: Yes you should avoid it.Instead choose other alternative mentioned in the above link.